# JQuery TypeError: object is undefined ( length = object.length, )

Tags: javascript

Everytime I use var.length I got an Error:

```
TypeError: object is undefined
length = object.length,
```

My JQuery Code:

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
   var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
   for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
       var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
       if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
           return sParameterName[1];
       }
   }
}
```

Meanwhile the URL:

```
login.html?error=autoLogout?from=request
```

Does anybody know how I can solve this Problem?

Comment: Your url is invalid. It should be `login.html?error=autoLogout&from=request`.

Comment: Your javascript is fine, the question is, where is object(or var) being defined? And as Jaydo pointed out, your url has 1 too many question marks, which I've chopped up to being a typo and ignored in my tests.

Comment: @Jaydo got it here - your function works fine if you correct the URL formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because the url is wrong.
It should be like:

login.html?error=autoLogout&from=request

Because the url is wrong when you try to get the 'from' parameter you receive an undefined so on an undefined if you try to get the length the system responds you with that message: TypeError: object is undefined.

If you do not want to change the url in order to adapt your function to your url you may do:

```
    function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1).replace('?', '&');
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well this works fine, but I also got the same error on 
` 
    var date = new Date(); 
    var stunden = date.getHours(); 
    if (stunden.toString().length === 1) { stunden = "0" + stunden; }
`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. However, the link you are using is incorrect.It should be :
login.html?error=autoLogout&from=request

you can have a look at the link below also
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string